# Can't find view in bottom sheet with Espresso

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, android-espresso

I have a Fragmant that contains a `CoordinatorLayout` with two children: a `MapView` (Google Maps API) & a `RelativeLayout`, this last layout contains some buttons that I want to test using `Espresso`.

So here's my test:

```
@Test
fun randomButtonTest() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000)
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    // Find the button and perform a click
    val appCompatImageButton = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.random_poi), withContentDescription("Random Point of Interest"),
                    withParent(withId(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)),
                    isDisplayed()))
    appCompatImageButton.perform(click())

}
```

And here is my layout (I have removed all layout related parameters for visibility):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"            
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/up_arrow" />  

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/random_poi"
            android:contentDescription="@string/random_poi"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I get the following error when launching my instrumented test:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: kade.com.accio:id/random_poi and with content description: is "Random Point of Interest" and has parent matching: with id: kade.com.accio:id/design_bottom_sheet and is displayed on the screen to the user)

Is that because my button is in a bottom sheet? Why can't I find this view?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to load the fragment (otherwise there is no fragment to test) so there are two ways

1.) instantiate your fragment object and load using FragmentManager like

```
   @Before  // you can do it later 
    void setup(){
       fragment = ...    
       getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(id,farment).commit()
 // or  activityTestRule.getActivity()
 //           .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

   }
```

Note: if your views are going out of screen then you can use `withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)` instead of `isDisplayed()`

Comment: This seems to be a step up, thank you, but I get the following error:
> Error performing 'single click' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.
after replacing `isDsplayed()` with what you have shared.

Comment: @Christopher make sure to follow [Set up your test environment](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup.html#set-up-environment) to `On your device, under Settings > Developer options, disable settings:`and you need to use `withEffectiveVisibility` when your target views are not visible on the screen